# Unity 22's ground track; which direction was it moving horizontally at 1085 kph during its weightless phase?

Tags: mission-design, virgin-galactic, ground-track

**update:** According to The Newyorker's [The Red Warning Light on Richard Branson’s Space Flight](https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-red-warning-light-on-richard-bransons-space-flight) there is FR24 data available.

---

[image: screenshot of Unity 22's altitude and speed at apogee]

A quick check of the videos shows Virgin Galactic's Unity 22's apogee of over 86 km, and at that point the displayed speed is 674 mph or about 1085 kph or 18.1 km per minute. During the four minutes of being weightless we can assume the trajectory to be roughly parabolic so the horizontal speed should be fairly constant, meaning it traveled at least 70 km horizontally during that time alone.

**Question:** Which direction (azimuth) was Unity 22 moving horizontally at 1085 kph during its 4 minute weightless phase? What direction relative to the spaceport (towards, away-from, parallel to, etc.)?

Comment: **1** What do you mean by "why no go straight up?". It is on a parabolic trajectory. the 70 km traveled would have been only approximately horizontal; IMO. **2** What do you mean by "which direction was ...". By direction, did you mean heading (north, east, west south etc.) ?

Comment: @AJN 1) No. The 70 km is the horizontal distance component. By checking the velocity **at apogee** (first sentence, when there is no vertical component) the speed displayed must be of the horizontal velocity, and the way parabolic flight works it will have essentially the same horizontal velocity throughout those four minutes of weightlessness. 2) Azimuth would indeed be the easiest way to express the horizontal velocity of the ground track, yes. I can't think of any other way off-hand.

Comment: @AJN "What do you mean by 'why no go straight up?'" If it went straight up relative to the surface it wouldn't have any horizontal velocity. Since it's traveling at mach 1.1  at the peak of the parabola, it's definitely not going straight up.

Comment: "Which direction was Unity 22 moving horizontally at 1085 kph during its 4 minute weightless phase; why not go straight up instead?" These look like 2 separate questions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble you're right, I'll separate "why not..." into a separate question.

Comment: @uhoh I don't understand the question "Why no go straight up?". Do you mean to ask why the trajectory of the aircraft was designed / decided to be a parabolic trajectory with some significantly large horizontal velocity at apogee ?

Comment: @AJN Yes, and the horizontal velocity *is constant for parabolic flight*, it's just the vertical velocity that changes. That part has been moved to a separate question: companion question: [Why did Unity 22 flight plan call for such a large horizontal velocity during its weightless phase?? (1085 kph) Why not go straight up instead?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54101/12102) (technically it's elliptical flight)