# Why did Unity 22 flight plan call for such a large horizontal velocity during its weightless phase? (1085 kph) Why not go straight up instead?

Tags: mission-design, virgin-galactic, ground-track

[image: screenshot of Unity 22's altitude and speed at apogee]

A quick check of the videos shows Unity 22's apogee of over 86 km, and at that point the displayed speed is 674 mph or about 1085 kph or 18.1 km per minute. During the four minutes of being weightless we can assume the trajectory to be roughly parabolic so the horizontal speed should be fairly constant, meaning it traveled at least 70 km horizontally during that time alone.

**Question:** Why did Unity 22 flight plan call for such a large horizontal velocity during its weightless phase? (1085 kph) Why not go straight up instead?

Comment: companion question [Unity 22's ground track; which direction was it moving horizontally at 1085 kph during its weightless phase?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54098/12102)

Comment: AIUI, but no documentary proof at this time: The purpose of the large horizontal component is so that the vehicle hits the high atmosphere at a higher rate of speed, and slows down sooner due to increased drag from the higher speed, *before* it slams into the "hard" atmosphere at about 30km and splatters itself.  I.e. it is done to lower the maximum g-force curve.

Comment: @PcMan Close; the horizontal velocity component helps the airframe to produce body lift in the thin high atmosphere, reducing the vertical velocity on the way down.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ah.. I was unaware that the vessel would generate meaningful lift in the "shuttlecock" configuration. I thought that was maximum drag+passive stability only.

Comment: I think we're both right -- the shuttlecock config probably produces both some lift and high drag.

Answer (score 5):

This ballistic "space" ship started as a plane and was landed as a plane too. To fly as a plane horizontal speed was necessary. When the hybrid rocket engine was ignited, the ship gained vertical speed. Conservation of energy is valid for such ships too, therefore the horizontal component of speed was not changed. To avoid any waste of rocket fuel and a reduction of the weightless time, the fuel should be used for vertical acceleration only and not to change horizontal speed. Going straight up would waste rocket fuel to reduce horizontal speed to zero.

The duration of the weightless time did not depend on horizontal speed, this time is only influenced by vertical speed. The air at a height of about 86 km is very thin, horizontal speed is not reduced by atmospheric drag.

Comment: Is there a source for the statement "fuel was used for vertical acceleration only" ? I found [this](https://youtu.be/5rMFuqhv30U?t=3557). apparently called "gamma turn". [Another point on same video](https://youtu.be/5rMFuqhv30U?t=3652).